# Space between CardView increases as cardElevation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-cardview

The gap between cardviews in a recyclerview increases as I increase card elevation

```
      <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="12dp"
        app:cardElevation="20dp"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">
```

[image]

then the space between items adds up the card elevation on both card views since I have set app:cardUseCompatPadding to true.I tried wrapping card view in another LinearLayout and making it as the recyclerview item but still the same result came.
Anyone has a better solution than setting negative padding/margin?

Comment: It will definitely increase you can disable app:cardUseCompatPadding="true" and set to false and can give margins.